# Django - UploadFile - Change name

Tags: django, filenames, filefield

I need to rename the file with the name of the variable.

I Have this:

```
    def content_file_name_Left(instance, filename):
        return 'user_{0}/Left/{1}'.format(instance.ID, filename)

...

     user_ImageLeft = models.FileField(default='', upload_to=content_file_name_Left)
```

I want that its save in: user_x/Left/**user_ImageLeft**.[format]

I have 20 images and I don't want make 20 functions for write manually the name of the variable.

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this and the best way seems to be by using a deconstructible class (deconstructible is used to prevent migration errors):

```
@deconstructible
class PathAndUniqueFilename(object):
    def __init__(self, sub_path):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        self.path = self.path.format(instance.user.id)
        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)
```

and then call this in your model like so:

```
user_ImageLeft = models.FileField(default='', upload_to=PathAndUniqueFilename('user_{0}/Left/'))
```

What this does is take the parameters of `PathAndUniqueFilename('user_{0}/Left/')`, and uses `format()` in the deconstructible in order to add a custom folder name.